# "python manage.py runserver" vs "django-admin runserver"

Tags: python, django

I have an app, Scaffold, installed, that runs perfectly when I use `python manage.py runserver` but when I try to start it using django-admin, it fails;

```
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I try calling it with `django-admin migrate --settings=scaffold.settings`
And I get; `ImportError: No module named scaffold.settings`

I've tried multiple things, googled around, but can't seem to figure out what I need to change. The settings.py file is in the directory ..\scaffold but I am no longer certain that is the one I need to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be using `manage.py` unless have a specific reason for not wanting project-specific configuration. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py)

> manage.py is automatically created in each Django project. manage.py is a thin wrapper around django-admin that takes care of several things for you before delegating to django-admin:
>
> - It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
> - It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.
> - It calls django.setup() to initialize various internals of Django.

Comment: I see. But isn't manage.py being deprecated? Adding a superuser and all should be done via django-admin now right?

Comment: have you go a link for this? running django admin operations with superuser privileges would be highly insecure

Comment: Nevermind. I misunderstood. Manage.py just wraps django-admin. Thank you for the answer, it is correct.