# django-admin cannot find settings module

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run `django-admin runserver` but I get this error:

```py
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'App'
```

I am using pipenv so I made a `.env` file in the cwd and I have the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` pointing at`src.App.settings`
I haven't made any sort of modifications, I believe, except running the server once with `./src/manage.py runserver` (it automatically created an sqlite3 db). [Here is the file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XetR.png)

I can run the server perfectly fine if I run it through manage.py though

Answer (score 0):

You can use uwsgi to run a django project.

First install uwsgi using:

```
pip install uWSGI
```

Go to project folder and enter this in terminal:

## Replace server with whatever is your project name

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module Server.wsgi
```

if you are not interested in install another module then there is no way to runserver locally

Comment: yes but @Pavan kuman there must be a way to run the server without the manage.py file

Comment: Just 'App' to installed apps in settings.py

Comment: But why use a 3rd party module though?
I mean, django can run it without a 3rd party app I believe

Comment: Add app to installed apps

Comment: django-admin runserver localhost:port number

Comment: I have't tried uWSGI but yeah, without it, it gives that error
I haven't done anything though

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question that was asked, you can check it out.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32199813/12640905

However, my guess is that the python installation that you’re using isn’t the same as the pip environment that you’re installing the packages into.

Comment: Its a pipenv environment

Comment: I see, but could you clarify why is it that you don't want to use manage.py?

Comment: No I mean, I could use it but it seems like I'm doing something wrong
I'm just curious to know how to fix django-admin