# ImproperlyConfigured Error for Django application

Tags: python, django, command-line, web-applications, command-line-interface

I keep getting an Improperly Configured Error when I try to run my server

Error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I created a new django project,
I have django installed in my virtual environment,
I did not forget to activate the virtual environment,
And I triple checked my python path,
Here is the full traceback:

```
(venv3) C:\Users\user\Desktop\trialproject>django-admin.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\trialproject\venv3\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\trialproject\venv3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Someone please help me figure out the problem. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting this error just after installation of django or did you changed anything in files?

Comment: Are you using settings.configure() somewhere before Django loads settings...

Comment: [“python manage.py runserver” vs “django-admin runserver”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199621/python-manage-py-runserver-vs-django-admin-runserver)

Answer (score 0):

that usually happen when you want to run your server with wrong virtual environment.
make sure you have the right virtual environment and try this :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**UPDATE** : check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error) is useful for you

Comment: I still get the same error. I used the right virtual environment.